When exporting an undefined identifier, tsc does not report a syntax error
I am using tsc to execute the following program:
enum e51 {
    HTML = 'html',
    JSON = 'json',
    CSV = 'csv',
}

export default ResponseType;

In the program I provided,"ResponseType" is undefined,and also is not referenced in other files.As a result, tsc did not report any errors. I want to know, is it because this identifier is undefined and unused that tsc ignored this line of code when translating?

The ResponseType type is provided by lib.dom.d.ts, and you're apparently exporting it. If you actually used an undefined identifier (e.g., export default ResponseThingy) you'd get an error. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

Yes, thank you for your detailed analysis. I have gained a clearer understanding of this issue.

ResponseType is a known type declared in TypeScript's standard DOM library.
type ResponseType = "basic" | "cors" | "default" | "error" | "opaque" | "opaqueredirect";

TypeScript Playground
Therefore, the compiler doesn't complain about an undeclared variable or type. You can explicitly disable the automatic inclusion of any library files with the --noLib compiler option set to false.
Caveat!

TypeScript cannot compile anything without a set of interfaces for key primitives like: Array, Boolean, Function, IArguments, Number, Object, RegExp, and String. It is expected that if you use noLib you will be including your own type definitions for these.

